# Pointers in Java

Tags: java, pointers, memory

C++ supports pointers whereas Java does not. But when many programmers questioned how you can work without pointers, the promoters began saying "Restricted pointers.” So we can say Java supports Restricted pointers?

Comment: Java does not support sale of roasted nuts

Comment: I have no clue what restricted pointers are supposed to be; I guess they were talking about Java's object references...

Comment: C++ supports pointer.. agreed! but Java does not support pointers? @nik Java automatically handles all variables at pointer level. So in Java you need not explicitly use pointers... That's all I know.

Comment: Millions of programmers can work without pointers, so the question should be: why do so many programmers need pointers to be able to work? :>

Comment: @Andreas: *most* interesting things that get done with pointers can *equally well* be done with more restricted Java-style references. There are a few exceptions, of course.

Comment: You pretty much can't do anything without pointers (or at least references in Java) in an imperative language like C/C++ or Java. On the other hand there're functional languages where there's really no need in pointers.

Comment: Like Kaiser said in an answer below - Java has pointers they are simply not designed to be directly utilized by developers. If you really want to go direct you can use the sun.misc.unsafe package.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The terminology is quite fuzzy here.

Java supports what it calls "references". References act  *a lot* like pointers in C/C++-like languages. They **don't** act the same way "references" work in those languages.

The *major* differences between a pointer in C and a reference in Java are:

- You can't do pointer arithmetic in Java (i.e. you can't "add" or "subtract" from a Java reference, you can *only* dereferencere it or compare it with another one).
- You can't cast it to an incompatible type: Java is strongly type-safe, you can't "re-interpret" the bytes in memory as some other object.

For *some* uses of pointers this has no real effect (for example linked lists work pretty much the same in both languages), for others the difference is quite major (arrays in C are just fancy pointer arithmetic, in Java they work quite differently).

So in a way Java references could be called "restricted pointers".

[Wikipedia defines a pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) as

> ... a programming language data type whose value refers **directly** to (or "points to") another value

Emphasis mine. According to this *strict* definition, Java doesn't have pointers.

The more general [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29) is the superclass of pointers, but also contrains more abstract things like file handles or even URLs.

Comment: Another difference: while you can (with some effort, unreliably) arrive at something reminiscent of a memory address for an object using `Object#toString`, I don't think there is a way to take such an address and get an object back. There's certainly no way to change the value held at that address.

Comment: can only add that pointers (or references - whatever you prefer) are managed - i.e. JVM knows about every pointer for the object so that GC can do its job.

Comment: @DanielLyons: A more direct way to get that value is `System.identityHashCode()` and while it *may* be based on the memory address, it most likely isn't, for two reasons: 1.) it's 32bit long, which would be too little in a 64bit VM with uncompressed references and 2.) it won't ever change on an object, even if the GC moves the object around in memory.

Comment: -1 "According to this strict definition, Java doesn't have pointers" is incorrect (logic). Furthermore, the Java language spec uses the term pointer. So yes, Java has pointers, *by definition*.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: the OP is obviously asking from an understanding of pointers derived from C++, not the Java language spec. Use of the same word does not automatically mean the same concept is in play, especially when standards (which are prone jargon redefinition) are involved.

Comment: @Daniel: let's leave telepathy out of this.

Comment: This answer is missing a major difference: in C++ you can take the address of anything (free-store allocated object, static object, stack-allocated object, function, etc...); in Java you can only have references to Objects, which must be allocated on the GC heap.

Comment: @Mankarse: That *is* a big difference, but I don't think it's a fundamental difference between pointers and references. Feel free to post it in your own answer.

Answer (score 8):

Another important different between Java and C/C++ is that references are an index to an object. Whereas in C/C++ a pointer is an address in memory.

In the 32-bit JVM, they are the same thing, however in the 64-bit JVM they are not.  Where you will notice this difference is that for heap sizes less than 32 GB, references are still 32-bit (even in a 64-bit JVM) This is because objects are allocated on an 8 byte boundary, so the index can refer to up to 32 GB of memory (4 G * 8 bytes)

In a 64-bit C/C++ programs, a pointer needs to be able to reference every byte even though memory allocation is on a 16 byte boundary and so it is 64-bit in size (technically it should be possible to make it 32-bit for less than 4 GB of memory.)

A [smart pointer](http://warp.povusers.org/RefPtr/) needs two underlying pointers (for a total of 16 bytes) but on gcc, the minimum allocation size for the reference count is 32 bytes (And then you have the size of the object you point to)  The total size is 32 bytes + 16 bytes per pointer.  c.f. 4 bytes per reference in Java. (8 bytes if you have 32+ GB of heap)

In summary, a Java reference doesn't have to be the actual address or even the same size as a pointer. It certainly much smaller than a smart pointer.

Comment: These are implementation details that don't change the substance.
In abstract terms, a "pointer" is "something that tells you where something else is". (Even a file name or an URL, in this sense is a "pointer").
The implementation can refer to as many level of indirection wants, and can "hide" to the user some of them, but -generally speaking- pointer, reference, restricted pointers, array indexes, are different syntactic sugar for a same concept: "indirection"

Comment: +1: I agree that indirection is the most important similarity, a valuable comment.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to understand "restricted pointers". Excerpt from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29):

> One major problem with pointers is that as long as they can be
>   directly manipulated as a number, they can be made to point to unused
>   addresses or to data which is being used for other purposes. Many
>   languages, including most functional programming languages and recent
>   imperative languages like Java, replace pointers with a more opaque
>   type of reference, typically referred to as simply a reference, which
>   can only be used to refer to objects and not manipulated as numbers,
>   preventing this type of error. Array indexing is handled as a special
>   case.

What it means is that in Java, you can't add or subtract to a pointer since memory management is done by the JVM itself.

Java adopted [*reference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29). References have types, just like in C, and they're typesafe as these reference cannot be interpreted as raw address and unsafe conversion is not allowed.

Comment: Reference and pointers are different syntactic sugar for a same abstract concept: "indirection".

Between the C++ a->fn() and the java a.fn() there is no difference.
Simply Java doesn't have an equivalent for the C++ a.fn().
So java has pointers it calls "reference" (different than C++ reference, since they are mutable) and doesn't have object stack allocation.

Answer (score 3):

When people say that Java doesn't support pointers, they are practicing
newspeak.  What Java calls references correspond exactly to what has
always been known as pointers in the past.

What Java doesn't support is pointer arithmetic.  Which is something
else entirely; as far as I know, C and its descendents are the only
typed languages which support pointer arithmetic.  Pascal and Modula-2,
for example, have "pointers", described as pointers in their
specifications, but these pointers have a semantic far closer to that of
Java references; they don't allow pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

Java actually *does* have pointer math. It comes with sun.misc.Unsafe. However, you have to manage the memory yourself - be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Java has pointers.  That's why it has a NullPointerException.  It just doesn't have pointer math.  Any reference to an object is actually a pointer, which is why it can be null.  That said, there are plenty of useful programming languages which don't have pointers, so anyone who thinks that pointers are necessary for programming has a very narrow view of programming languages.

Comment: The naming of that exception is quite unfortunate, because it's the *only* place where references are called pointers. The JLS and the JVM spec always talk about references.

Comment: @Joachim: You are wrong. "JLS and the JVM spec always talk about references" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let me be acid: 
Java don't have pointers because it's designers decided to call them differently.
In fact they moved everything on the heap so that everything is managed by a pointer, then, since no direct reference existed anymore, canceled the "." and renamed "->" as "."

Comment: -1 "Java don't have pointers because it's designers decided to call them differently" is wrong. You might make a case by talking about simple-minded Java practitioners. But that's something else...

Comment: @Alf: yes, there is something else: marketing decision about syntax and names to give to concepts.
C++ and Java target both Von Newman machines. They have pointers by the very nature. You can "hide it", but cannot do without.

Answer (score 1):

The **[Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3.1)** has this to say about the matter:

> **Java Language Spec §4.3.1**
>   The reference values (often just references) are *pointers* to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

For those who fear delving into documentation, the presence of e.g. Java’s `NullPointerException` should be a strong indication that Java does have pointers.

In short, the question is meaningless because it is based on a totally incorrect assumption that, quoting the OP, “Java does not pointers”  –  as proven above, that is technically bullshit.

See also [James Kanze’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480783/pointers-in-java/7481573#7481573).

This answer can best be viewed as just supplying the necessary references to James’ answer.

Cheers & hth.

Answer (score -1):

Pointers are just a way to make mutible return. They not really importend for effektiv work. It is easier to use and you can understand the code better than with pointers. In the most source code in c, I see the more &/*/-> than other things and you have ever look if you need it.