# How are linked lists implemented without the use of pointer?

Tags: java, c++

It is easy to implement linked list in c++ where you have pointers. But how are they implemented in other languages (like java,python,etc). I don't want to use built-in class(which are supported in JAVA) for linked-list but what i want is how to replace pointers to create linked-list?

Comment: Read this, and see if it sufficiently addresses your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480783/pointers-in-java

Comment: @asawyer Nothing is passed by reference in Python and Java. Neither in many other languages that use references in the same sense.

Comment: @asawyer: agree with delnan. Java is pass by value. Always. That value may be a reference, but a value is what is passed.

Comment: I haven't done java in years, cheerfully withdrawn!

Comment: @asawyer I haven't done Java *ever* ;)

Comment: @delnan all mutable values in python (lists, sets, etc.) are passed by reference.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple They are not. All values (mutable *and* immutable -- **stop making a distinction up** folks) are *reference types*, but parameter passing is never *pass by reference* (edit: confusing typo). Both are technical terms with very specific, and distinct, meaning. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/395760

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They are implemented using references which are essentially (excluding syntax) pointers that you can't do pointer arithmetic with (in some languages they also can't be null). In many languages, references are the default way of using variables, unlike C++ where the default is by-value.

Comment: +1 I love that explanation for references. It is so quick, easy and accurate, aside from being obvious for C veterans and giving others a reason to learn that aspect of programming.

Answer (score 5):

With other languages, you deal with references which are closely related to pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pointers that point to a block of memory, references are used, as stated before. So like you would have in C++

```
Struct Node {
  Node *last;
  Node *next;
}
```

it would look like this:

```
Struct Node {
  Node last;
  Node next;
  }
```

Comment: The last sentence is unfortunate. If we take it as face value, i.e. "`Node` is a value type", it implies your second definition of `Node` is invalid because it is on infinite size. References are not addresses indeed, but they *are* indirections.

Comment: I just noticed that your second example is invalid even ignoring the now removed explanation. (If it's supposed to be C++ that is.)

Comment: It was simply supposed to be a visualization in pseudocode. The Struct just came from his background in C++

Answer (score 1):

A good data structures class will show you that a linked list can be implemented in any language using arrays, such as FORTRAN.

Instead of using pointers, you would use some other means to locate the next link.  With arrays, instead of a pointer you would use an index to the next element.

Thus you could implement a linked list in a random-access file by using the file position instead of pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as linked list. It definitely has different characteristics from the pointer-based implementation, in that it is more limited. Apart from that, this is entirely beside the point because you *can* build "regular" linked lists (and all other data structures relying on indirection) with references.

Comment: It is a list, and it is linked.  It doesn't use pointers to link the nodes.  It is a different *implementation* of a linked list.  I was taught this in my Data Structures class at the University.

Answer (score 0):

When you write your own class, say `class node`, and have each `node` hold a field to the next  `node`, You actually hold a reference to that next node (or null if it's the last one)

Answer (score 0):

You may find a good answer in this book - [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) - I'll summarize what I recall for you.

Basically you'll have two arrays of equal size (hopefully larger than n where n=number of elements you want to store).  We'll call them Array A and Array B.

Array A[i] holds the data value.  Array B[i] holds the 'next' value 'k' such that A[i]->next = A[k].

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: See my comment on Thomas Matthew's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the concept of a linked list is that you can get from one element to another. How you do it can be very different.

In C++ for example you mentioned you can use pointers. Which said another way would be that you use the objects memory address.

But that's just one way. If all your objects were referenced from an array, then you would be able to reference an object by it's index on that array. So each element in your linked list would have a integer specifying the index of the object it's connected to.

To give you another example. If you had a dictionary where you associated objects with strings. Then you could use strings to reference each other.

The core concept to linked lists is not pointers, it's that the elements in the list are responsible to keep track of the element it's connected to.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER : this is my assumption. I might be wrong. If I am wrong, please correct me**

**Example Program (Primitive Data Type)**

1. Creating a new space for int and store a value  (int a = 5)
2. (int b = a) this code represents the (int b) as a new space and the value of (int a) is passed.

**Example Program (User Define Data Type)**

1. Creating a new space for class (Solution obj= new Solution();)

   In this code, the (Solution = DataType), (obj = variable),
   (Solution()=default constructor)

   The new keyword helps to create new space for a default constructor
   (which means the default constructor contains the class member of
   datatypes and methods)
   The way to create a new space for class (only by using the new keyword)
2. Solution obj = new Solution();

   Solution ref = obj;

   See the difference between Class and Primitive Data Type. The new space
   was not created for the Solution ref class, because we didn't use the
   new keyword and constructor. So the ref just hold the obj references,
   but in Primitive Data Type (int b) we don't need a new keyword to create
   a space.