# Pointer manipulation in java

Tags: java, pointers

What are the reasons for restricting Java not to support Pointer Manipulations?

Comment: Just see what mess it causes in C++ ad C

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480783/pointers-in-java

Comment: That is the reason I love java.No mess,No fuss  :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080617/why-doesnt-java-have-pointers

Comment: Please use Google first. There are plenty of tutorials on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is improved security. When Java doesn't allow pointers, the programmer is not allowed to freely step around in the computer memory. You also get rid of the C/C++ problem "undefined behavior". The rule of not having pointers in Java is also consistent with the way methods are supposed to be called in Java compared to C/C++ (call by reference).

Answer (score 0):

See if you have pointers with you you are free to access physical memory locations that may be used by another process.Which will let you change content at that location corrupting the data used by another process. Pointer therefore pose issues of security and data corruption.
Hacking other process's memory is not at all a good idea.