# Access cpu registers

Tags: java, assembly, cpu, cpu-registers

Is there any way to access / modify the cpu's registers from Java just like in Assembly? (eax, rip, ax, etc.)
I don't know if it would be useful in any way, but I think it would be quite interesting.

And is there a way to get the "save point" of variables like in c / c++:

```
&variable
```

Thanks in advance, I hope you've understood what I mean.

Comment: Akim, what happens if your Java program runs on ARM/MIPS/PowerPC/software simulation? It is not possible to get the address of an object or variable - the JVM is allowed to move them at will.

Comment: It would be possible but you would be dependent on underlying architectural applications or libraries. I don't think java is meant to work on that level.

Comment: Short answer no. Long answer yes, but you'll need to use native code. JNI or JNA.

Comment: interesting question, however i think that's not java meant for at all!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer : **No**

Java is compiled in a cross-plateform byte code. Assembly is plateform specific.

Regarding the "save point" they are called pointers in c/c++, and in Java, you are manipulating references.

For more details about pointers and references, see [Pointers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480783/pointers-in-java)

Comment: Are you sure that it's not possible? e.g. native method?

Comment: @Maksym I think that "no" as "not possible" is correct answer to question "_I don't know if it would be useful in any way, but I think it would be quite interesting_". If OP does not even know what is happening inside the JVM and JIT (or AOT) then trying to hack some side effects of a JNI call or of the JVM internal state is not the way to go towards "something useful"

Comment: I am not saying about usability of this feature... The question was "Is there any way to access / modify the cpu's registers from Java"... We don't know what author is doing , maybe he writes some hack for another program that uses register. If you ask me would I use Java for that, my answer I will be not, but we cannot say that it's not possible.

Comment: @Maksym although the `JVM` can access `CPU` registers and native code attached to the `JVM` through the `JNI` interface (or `JNA`) can also access `CPU` registers it does not mean there is a way to access `CPU` registers from `Java` ("_..just like in assembly.._"). See also https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/safejni.pdf (and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/259228)

Answer (score 1):

Since Java runs inside a virtual machine it is not possible to access low-level hardware such as the registers of your CPU. Especially because their representation and presence may change from one system to another. In addition, accessing registers might be a security violation as well.

You also cannot determine an object's memory address with just using java. Also because the program resides in said virtual machine. You may get the position inside the JVM's Heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

**You should not do it**. Java is a high-level language and can handle your task without needs of usage cpu register. In fact JVM can use cpu register if it will be needed for optimization.

You can protect usage of CPU cache with **volatile**.

Anyway you can try to write own **native** method, not sure that it will be successful.